# multiselect.js all options moving over and cannot remove them

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, multi-select

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jenborn/pam6X/1/

In the fiddle it's working, but on my page, when I click any of the options in the multi-select all of them move over and it won't let me remove any of them.  I'm sure that I have something configured incorrectly.  Also, I'm using Foundation 4, jquery validator, and I'm hoping that it's not conflicting.

In the header:

```
<link href="./multiselect/css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="./multiselect/js/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The HTML:

```
    <select id="pref" multiple="multiple">
        <option value='1'>Ooga</option>
        <option value='2'>Booga</option>
        <option value='4'>Hubba</option>
        <option value='3'>Bubba</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a conflict with Foundation 4's Custom Forms.  When I remove class="custom" from my form tag, it works properly.